# Ecclesiastes 12:9-11, could we discern some aspects of the personality of Jesus from these verses?

Tags: luke, ecclesiastes

Ecclesiastes 12:9-11, (DRB):

> 9And whereas Ecclesiastes was very wise, he taught the people, and declared the things that he had done: and seeking out, he set forth many parables. 10He sought profitable words, and wrote words most right, and full of truth.
> 11The words of the wise are as goads, and as nails deeply fastened in, which by the counsel of masters are given from one shepherd.

Could we discern some aspects of the personality of Jesus from these verses?

I mean, could we consider these verses as prophecy about Jesus?

I mean, are these verses applied to both Solomon and Jesus?

Look:

Luke 2:40, (DRB):

> 40And the child grew and waxed strong, full of wisdom: and the grace of God was in him.

Luke 2:46-47, (DRB):

> 46And it came to pass, that, after three days, they found him in the temple, sitting in the midst of the doctors, hearing them and asking them questions. 47And all that heard him were astonished at his wisdom and his answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Luke 24:25 He [Jesus] said to them, “How foolish you are, and how slow to believe all that the prophets have spoken! 26 Did not the Messiah have to suffer these things and then enter his glory?” 27 And beginning with Moses and **all** the Prophets, he explained to them what was said in **all** the Scriptures concerning **himself**.

In the general sense, yes, Ecclesiastes 12:9-11 prophecies or alludes to the coming Jesus.

Specifically,

1. Both Ecclesiastes and Jesus were very wise as the OP has pointed out.
2. Both were teachers.
3. Both set forth many parables (maxims).
4. Both are careful to choose the right words to show the full truth. John 6:63 The words I have spoken to you--they are full of the Spirit and life.
5. Both were shepherds of Israel. John 10:11 I am the good shepherd.

However, compared to Jesus, Ecclesiastes was only a shadow of the real thing.